# Sed File separation with delimiters

Tags: shell, sed

I have the following sed commands to split a file in two:

```
sed -n '1,/(-!-)/{/(-!-)/!p}' file.temp file1.txt
sed -n '/(-!-)/,${/(-!-)/!p}' file.temp file2.txt
```

the file is like 123 (-!-) 321

and I got this result:

file1:
123

file2:
321

this works just great but I wanted it split to 4 files, it means I will use 3 separators

Can someone give me a hint about how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` is probably not the right tool for this job.  `awk`, on the other hand, is able to split records on arbitrary regular expressions, which ends up making this very easy.  First, here's a way to extract a particular section from your file.

Given this input:

```
this is section 1
(-!-)
this is section 2
(-!-)
this is section 3
```

We can extract just section three like this:

```
awk -vRS='\n[(]-!-[)]\n' 'NR==3 {print}' file.temp
```

Which gives us:

```
this is section 3
```

In this command, we're setting awk's record separator (the `RS` variable) to a regular expression matching the separator in your file.  Normally, `awk` uses a newline as the record separator, so each line is a new record.  By setting `RS` explicitly to this regular expression, we are making `awk` treat each section as a single entity.

You can extract each section into a separate file like this:

```
awk -vRS='\n[(]-!-[)]\n' -vprefix="file" '{print > prefix NR}' file.temp
```

This will give you the files `file1`, `file2`, and `file3` as output, each containing the content of the appropriate section.  The filenames are generated from the value of the "prefix" variable (set by the `-vprefix="file"` option ) and the current record number.

Comment: +1, Great explanation, and I didn't know output redirection was so easy from inside `awk`!

Comment: I should note that this is assuming GNU `awk`; classic `awk` only supports single-character record separators (the `RS` variable).

Comment: +1, though you don't really need a variable. You can simply do `gawk -vRS='\n[(]-!-[)]\n' '{print > "file"NR".txt"}'` to store each line in file1.txt, file2.txt .. etc

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<! >file.temp
> aaa
> (-!-)
> bbb
> (-!-)
> ccc
> (-!-)
> ddd
> !
csplit -n1 -ffile file.temp '/(-!-)/' '{*}'
sed -i '/(-!-)/d' file?
```